# Case Auto response rule with case owner not working

Tags: record-type, email2case, case-auto-response

My case auto response is very simple. All the cases are assigned to a queue called "test". In case auto response rule my criteria is "case owner= queue name(test)". rule is active and email template has been assigned(available for use). I don't see any auto response email after case creation in sandbox. Are they any other settings I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandboxes by default will not deliver emails. You can [enable email deliverability](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm&type=5) in your sandbox or find a non-email way of verifying activity triggering e.g. updating a checkbox field.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000wlmsAAA

Comment: Thank you. In email deliverability  settings, it needs to be "All email" instead of "system Email"